# Creating Charts - Chart Helper Deprecated

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It seems Chart Helper is no longer available in asp.net 5 MVC 6.  How do we create charts in asp.net 5?  I cant find anything in the docs or via google.

The chart helper was great but I presume its removed as it was part of system.web.

Without using **paid** third party software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trend in ASP.NET 5 is to get somewhat away from everything being server side. The optimization framework got replaced in favor of gulp.js for example.

For graphs I suggest you opt for a client side alternative for which you render out data as json and make use of a dedicated library like [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) or any other client side library. There's a bunch of them and several are free.